# Avoid XAML Code Duplication

Tags: .net, wpf

I am very new to WPF. The UI I was required to implement makes use of buttons that contain both an image and a textual label. 
Creating one of these buttons is straightforward: I set the button's content to a UniformGrid and drop an image and a label into the grid.
However, since there are quite a few of these buttons in my GUI, how do I avoid copy-pasting the XAML that defines this button multiple times, and instead "refactor" it into something I can just code once and easily maintain later? Is a Custom Control considered overkill for this issue? Is there a simpler, built-in solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Control Templates to specify the visual tree of your buttons... Do a google search, there's heaps of good documentation and examples around...

Also, [TemplateBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) will allow you to pass properties from a control into the Template...

Ian